# how to store json in database

Tags: mysql, json

Is this better

```
{"details":{"number":"8","date":"29/06/2015","due_date":"06/07/2015"},
```

or this one:

```
%7B%22details%22%3A%7B%22number%22%3A%228%22%2C%22date%22%3A%2229%2F06%2F2015%22%2C%22due_date%22%3A%2206%2F07%2F2015%22
```

to store in a database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI encoding values is completely pointless. Just store it as a JSON string with no encoding whatsoever, as JSON is already an encoding format.

URI encoding should be *only* for URIs. It has no other applicability. If you do need to encode, for whatever reason, use something standard like Base64.

Remember that you'll want to keep values like this as readable as possible, not scramble them arbitrarily.

Comment: I was thinking of multibyte strings, that's why I encoded it. Is it pointless you say?

Comment: JSON is supposed to be UTF-8, so make sure your database and columns are as well.

Comment: As a note, you may need to use `utf8mb4` if you're looking to encode emoji-type characters like . This requires MySQL 5.5.4 or later.

Comment: Thanks. But actually they're french or dutch or german alphabet letters so I don't think I'll need a special encoding/decoding technique. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the first choice, because you can read it much easier, if you look for errors.

To go a little bit further. If you need to work with json structured data, think about using an OR mapper to safe the values of `number`, `date and`due_date`in separate columns in a table called`details`.

Comment: These values will be never read. They will be retrieved rarely and will be decoded with php.